# uGet not showing in System tray

Tags: unity, indicator, system-tray, uget

I have Ubuntu 13.04 with uGet 1.10.3 the problem is simple :
`uGet AppIndicator` not visible,`uGet` tray icon not visible

And this key was not found in my system settings:
`com.canonical.Unity.Panel->systray-whitelist`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your settings something like this? Need to make sure your tray icon is set to show.

[image: uGet Tray Settings]

Comment: This is originally  on

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the build in the Ubuntu repositories is causing the problem, and when upgraded, Uget (1.10.3-0)was upgraded to the version in the Ubuntu repository (1.10.3-1)
so here is how i fixed it :
I removed  uget :
`sudo apt-get remove --purge uget`

Then removed the config files :
`rm -rf '/home/abdou/.config/uGet'`

Downloaded & installed the version in the official site :
`wget https://launchpadlibrarian.net/138646189/uget_1.10.3-0ubuntu0%7Eraring_i386.deb`

`sudo dpkg -i uget_1.10.3-0ubuntu0~raring_i386.deb`

Comment: Thanks a lot but I moved up the tree and using Debian Wheezy